# How to do POST request in Codeception FunctionalTest with JSON Body

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii2, codeception

Im using Codeception with Yii2. I need to do a POST request with json content body. I dont want to use REST module cause have not even been able config it yet. (Thats a longer story...)

I have been able to write my GET tests fantastic. Now with the first POST test, Im stuck.

1. There is a `$I->amOnPage([])` method in Functional Test which can only do GET request.
2. `sendAjaxPost` does not allow sending content body with POST.
3. `$I->sendPOST('api/xyz',"{\"xyz\":1}")` also did not work cause Yii did not get any route so instead loaded the homepage. The path got lost in the call stacks.
4. There is a `InnerBrowser->_loadPage` method which allows me to do a request with all configurable way but I cannot find a way to access it.

Any way to get access to `InnerBrowser` object from the test?
I have tried `$I->getModule('PhpBrowser')->_loadPage` or `$this->getModule('Yii2')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [I->SendAjaxPostRequest](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Yii2#sendAjaxPostRequest) which has an array argument with the POST values to send with the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can update backend code to accept both raw inputs and params, so you can pass array in Codeception test and raw input in api

```
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    if(!$data) {
        $data = (object) Yii::$app->request->post ();
        $detail = (object) $data->detail;
    } else {
        $detail = $data->detail;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a new StepAction to your tests classes. Its not difficult:

in _support/FunctionalTester.php add:

```
public function sendPostRequest($uri, $parameters, $files = [], $server = [], $content = null) {
    return $this->getScenario()->runStep(new \Codeception\Step\Action('sendPostRequest', func_get_args()));
}
```

in _support/Helper/Functional.php add:

```
public function sendPostRequest($uri, $parameters, $files = [], $server = [], $content = null)  {
    return $this->getModule('Yii2')->_request('POST', $uri, $parameters, $files, $server, $content);
}
```

(change Yii2 into your module).

and then in your test:

```
 $this->sendPostRequest('/api/v1/users', json_decode($params));
```